# AutoMapper error: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: .net, automapper

In my solution there are a lot of projects. And Profile class is situated at project different from the one with Program file.

Although I did all as the textbook described, I got this error. And I register Mapper like this in my Program class:

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the #solution is to change registration in Program file:
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program)); ---> to this
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile).Assembly);
As MappingProfile is where we configure mapping and it's in different project with Program class.

In case - someone also is doing program following the textbook and stuck on that error.
In brief we need to point precise address of Profile class if we meet such error and we have a solution with a lot of projects.